# Htaccess подмена url

Tags: .htaccess

у меня есть url **http://site.ru/blog/cat/item** мне надо по этому url показывать содержимое **http://site.ru/cat/item**, но чтоб адрес оставался как в первом варианте.
я пытаюсь это сделать таким образом

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [L]
```

получаю 404 ошибку

Comment: прикол в том, что мне не нужен 301 редирект, а просто надо отображать страницу

Answer (score 3):

У вас ошибка в реализации:

Вы проверяете, есть ли в адресе `/blog/`. Затем говорите серверу брать данные для страниц, содержащих значение `/blog/` из аналогичных страниц, не содержащих этого значения. А таких страниц у вас нет. Иными словами, вы сделали все наоборот.

Вот так должно работать:

```
# По новому адресу загружаем содержимое со старого адреса
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/blog/$1 [L]
```

Comment: у меня редиректит и кучу plots подставило
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/areas/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.suite.ua/plots/$1 [L]